# Grade average in toString

Tags: java, tostring

I'm doing the dreaded grade average problem for my class and have run into MANY hiccups, but this one seems to be the major one.  I'm not able to pull the calculated average in my method to the `toString`. Here's the one method:

```
public void average() {

    total = (((quiz1 + quiz2) / 40 * 25) + (midterm / 100 * 35) + (finalExam / 100 * 40));
    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
    dec.format(total);
    return;

}
```

And I'm trying to get it here:

```
public String toString(){
    return ("Grade Report:\n" ....+ "Total Score     " + total + "\n" ....);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.  It was more to the problem (of course). I had to call it to a string from a driver program, where I thought it was all in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `average` method shouldn't set anything - it should just return the average. You can then format this number in your `toString` method:

```
public double average() {
    return (((quiz1 + quiz2)/40 * 25) + 
            (midterm/100 * 35) + 
            (finalExam/100 * 40));
}

public String toString(){
    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
    String averageString = dec.format(average();
    return ("The average score is " + averageString); // just an example
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your average method has declared `void` as its return type. It should probably actually return the value it calculates:

```
public String average(){

    total = (((quiz1 + quiz2)/40 * 25) + (midterm/100 * 35) + (finalExam/100 * 40));
    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
    return dec.format(total);
}

public String toString(){
    return ("Grade Report:\n" + average() + "Total Score     " + total + "\n" ....);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two mistakes:

- You're not returning the result of your `average` method, when you *probably* should be as opposed to storing it into a field.  That's easy enough to fix.
- You're likely dividing integers; if we can presume that `quiz1`, `quiz2`, `midterm` and `finalExam` are all `int`, then you won't get a floating point result back.

The first fix is easy:  remove the `total` field and replace it with a local variable.  Then, return the result of the format.

```
String total = ...

return dec.format(total);
```

Next, to ensure you don't divide ints, place some decimals in your quotient.

```
String total = (((quiz1 + quiz2) / 40.0 * 25) + (midterm / 100.0 * 35) + (finalExam / 100.0 * 40));
```